# Smooth Bezier Curve

Tags: bezier, smoothing, curve

I want to smooth some hand draw lines in iphone.
I have used the following code in 
http://webdocs.cs.ualberta.ca/~graphics/books/GraphicsGems/gems/FitCurves.c

However, I found that some bezier curved was wrong, the second control point and end point is invalid.
Did anybody have the same problem before?
Thanks.

Comment: You'll have to be more specific. Give an example.

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7211719/curve-fitting-a-series-of-line-segments/7211779#7211779).

Answer (score 2):

Bezier Curves are not designed to go **through** the provided vertices!
They are designed to shape a smooth curve **influenced** by the control points.

First you must decide if you want to interpolate between missing points, 
or if you want to filter non smooth data:

**Filtering**

You should look at "sliding average" with a small averaging window. (try 5 - 10 pixel).
This works as follows: (look for wiki for a detailed description)

I use here an average window of 10 points: 
start by calculation of the average of points 0 - 9, and output  the result as result point 0
then calculate the average of point 1 - 10 and output, result 1
And so on.

**Interpolation**
If you want to interpolate between (missing) points using a smooth curve, you could use piece - wise cubic splines:

You calculate the coefficients of a cubic polygon through 3 vertices.
You start with calculating the cubic polygon through:
Point[0] - Point[2], but you draw your output only from Point[0]  to Point[1] .
    Then you move on one step:  and calculate through
Point[1] - Point[3], but you draw only from p1 to p2.
And so on.

You need to search on wiki for cubic interpolation for a detailed explanation how to caluclate a cubic polygon (sometimes called cubic spline).