# Drawing splines in varying color segments

Tags: winapi, gdi+, gdi

I'm using GDI+ to draw a cardinal spline through a series of points.  I wish to draw certain segments in a different color.  I've tried drawing the segments individually with multiple [`Graphics::DrawCurve`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/gdiplusgraphics/nf-gdiplusgraphics-graphics-drawcurve(constpen_constpoint_int)) calls, but this short-circuits the smoothing algorithm and results in the connection between segments being sharp points, rather than curves.  I thought about a gradient brush, but I don't want a smooth color gradient, but rather an abrupt color change at certain points.  Is this possible without duplicating the spline algorithm and manually drawing point-by-point?

Comment: One option would be to draw the same curve multiple times, once for each color, and use clipping to prevent all but the segment in question from being rendered.

Comment: Thanks, that's actually a pretty good idea; it'd certainly be as fast or faster than a manual draw routine.  If you post it as an answer, I'll mark it so.

Comment: Maybe going via Bezier curves https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1257168/how-do-i-create-a-bezier-curve-to-represent-a-smoothed-polyline or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53679551/interpolating-a-cardinal-curve-in-c-sharp

Comment: @JonathanPotter, your suggestion of redrawing using clip regions was implemented and worked very well, if you'd like to post it as an actual answer.